# Get the document object for an Iframe?

Tags: jquery

How can I get the document object for an Ifarme  ?

I tried this :

`$(document,"#IFRM_Quest")[0]        //[object Document]`

and it works.

But I also tried :

`$("#IFRM_Quest").contents()[0]` which also yields document. `//[object Document]`

So why does

`$("#IFRM_Quest").contents()[0]===$(document,"#IFRM_Quest")[0]`

return false ?

this is suppose to be the same object...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHmlL.png
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(document,"#IFRM_Quest")[0]` does not select the document object of the iframe, it simply selects the document object of the current, uhm, document.

`document` is a variable directly referencing to the document object, not a selector. Your function call is equivalent to:

```
$(document)[0]
```

because whenever you pass a DOM element to jQuery, [the context is ignored](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9.1/src/core.js#L184):

```
// HANDLE: $(DOMElement)
} else if ( selector.nodeType ) {
    this.context = this[0] = selector;
    this.length = 1;
    return this;
}
```

This is actually also shown in the documentation in the function signattures:

> `jQuery( selector [, context ] )` `<-` optional context
>   `jQuery( element )`  `<-` no context

Comment: but isnt it a syntax for context ? `$(document,"#IFRM_Quest")` ??

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Only if you pass a *selector* as first argument, not a DOM element. If you already have a reference to a DOM element, jQuery does (and cannot) search for that element.

Comment: so this `$("#IFRM_Quest").contents()[0]` WILL give me the right document object ....correct ?

Comment: Yes, although I personally would do `$("#IFRM_Quest").get(0).contentDocument`, because it's more explicit.

Comment: yes but then youll have a cross browse problem : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3151793/859154   (contentDocument vs contentWindow)

Comment: `contentWindow` and `contentDocument` are two different objects. One refers to the `window` of the iframe (the global object), and the other to the `document` (a DOM element). But I have to admit that I don't know if those properties are supported in all browsers.

Comment: Felix I meant  (contentDocument vs contentWindow.document) they suppose to be the same object.

Comment: Oh I see... well, as I said, didn't know how cross-browser compatible those are :)